# Solving this Bernoulli equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

**Problem:** Solve the following differential equation: $$ x \frac{dy}{dx} + 6 y = 3x y^{4/3}. $$

**Attempt:** I rewrote this as $$ \frac{dy}{dx} = 3 y^{4/3} - \frac{6}{x} y $$ Now let $v = y^{1 - n}$. Then $v' = (1 - n) y^{-n} y'$ and so $$ \frac{v'}{(1 - n) y^{-n}} = 3 y^{4/3} - \frac{6}{x} y $$ or \begin{align*} v' &= (1 -n) y^{-n} \bigg(3 y^{4/3} - \frac{6}{x} y \bigg) \\ &= (1 -n) \bigg( 3 y^{4/3 - n} - \frac{6}{x} y^{1 - n} \bigg) \\ &= (1 - n) \bigg( 3 y^{1/3} v - \frac{6}{x} v \bigg) \end{align*} Now I don't know how to get rid of this $y^{1/3}$. I want it gone so I can separate for $v$ and $x$, and then solve. Help would be appreciated !

Comment: Hint: Do you know how to define $n$ in your substitution idea? It is the same with this question: do you know what $n$ means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice, you should substitute $n=4/3$ & $y^{1/3}=\frac{1}{v}$ for elimination.

Although, there is a simple & easy approach for the given differential equation. You should follow this.

the differential equation $$\frac{dy}{dx}=3y^{4/3}-\frac{6}{x}y$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}+\frac{6}{x}y=3y^{4/3}$$
$$y^{-4/3}\frac{dy}{dx}+\frac{6}{x}y^{-1/3}=3$$
Now, let $$v=y^{-1/3}\implies \frac{dv}{dx}=-\frac{1}{3}y^{-4/3}\frac{dy}{dx}$$$$\implies y^{-4/3}\frac{dy}{dx}=-3\frac{dv}{dx}$$
Hence, setting the corresponding values, we get $$-3\frac{dv}{dx}+\frac{6}{x}v=3$$
$$\frac{dv}{dx}-\frac{2}{x}v=-1$$
I think you can solve further the above linear differential equation

Answer (score 2):

This differential equation can also be written as an [exact differential equation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ExactFirst-OrderOrdinaryDifferentialEquation.html)

$$
p(x,y) + q(x,y) \frac{dy}{dx} = 0, \tag{1}
$$

where

$$
p(x,y) = 6y - 3xy^{4/3}, \tag{2}
$$

$$
q(x,y) = x. \tag{3}
$$

In order to solve the equation this way $p(x,y)$ and $q(x,y)$ have to satisfy

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} q(x,y) = \frac{\partial}{\partial y} p(x,y). \tag{4}
$$

For this differential equation this is not the case, but by multiplying the entire equation by some "integration factor", $\mu(x,y)$, the equation from (4) can become true.

Often finding $\mu(x,y)$ can be hard, but because in this case $q(x,y)$ is simple it is easy to guess the dependency of $\mu(x,y)$ on $y$, based on cancelling on of the two terms of $p(x,y)$ when the partial derivative is applied. Namely after applying the partial derivative with respect to $y$ the powers of all terms with $y$ will decrease by one, thus $\mu(x,y)=y^{-1}f(x)$, or $\mu(x,y)=y^{-4/3}f(x)$. Because for the first option the remaining terms, after partial differentiation, would be

$$
xy^{-2/3}f(x) = y^{-1}\left(xf'(x)+f(x)\right), \tag{5}
$$

it is already clear that this is not the correct option, since the powers of $y$ on both sides do not match. The second option, after partial differentiation, does return plausible results

$$
-2y^{-4/3} f(x) = y^{-4/3} \left(xf'(x) + f(x)\right). \tag{6}
$$

The expression for $f(x)$ can now be found by solving

$$
xf'(x) + 3 f(x) = 0, \tag{7}
$$

which can be done relatively easy with [separation of variables](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SeparationofVariables.html)

$$
\frac{df(x)}{f(x)} = -3 \frac{dx}{x} \to f(x) = c x^{-3}. \tag{8}
$$

The constant, $c$, which originates from the constant of integration of the indefinite integral, can be set to $1$, because multiplying the differential equation by a constant doesn't really change it and therefore the integration factor will be equal to

$$
\mu(x,y) = y^{-4/3} x^{-3}. \tag{9}
$$

The solution to equation (1) can now be found by integrating $\mu(x,y)p(x,y)$ with respect to $x$ and $\mu(x,y)q(x,y)$ with respect to $y$, adding them (but omitting double expressions) and equating it so some constant scalar potential, which can be found with a boundary condition

$$
-3y^{-1/3} x^{-2} + 3x^{-1} = C. \tag{10}
$$

Solving equation (10) for $y$ yields

$$
y(x) = \left(\frac{C}{3} x^2 + x\right)^{-3}. \tag{11}
$$